# Editor stats missing from new suggested edit screen

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I can't find the section of the new suggested edit review interface that shows editor and reviewer stats (e.g. "Editor has so many edit suggestions approved & so many edit suggestions rejected"). Can anyone tell me where can I find that? I've gone through the stats and history tabs, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for 2 hrs, I finally found out the answer. To see the Editor & Reviewer stats, there's link given in the top section which is labeled as ***"(more)"***. But still it doesn't show the last 5 suggested / reviewed edits of the Editor / Reviewer...:)

**Edit:**
@gnat, I'm attaching a screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: would you mind to add a screen shot to your answer? I tried to find editor stats following your description but somehow couldn't figure it